# Cannot upload file to transfer.sh. Error: could no save metadata

Tags: file-upload

Transfer.sh is a service that you can upload files by curl. I'm getting this error when I try to upload some file:

```
$ curl --upload-file file -s -w "\n" https://transfer.sh/
Could not save metadata
```

Comment: You can try using https://send.firefox.com/

Comment: @adamshamsudeen which curl command is used ?

Comment: You have to login to use firefox, give this a try https://oshi.at/cmd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service seems to be unstable.

You can use https://file.io

```
$ curl -F "file=@file" -s -w "\n"  https://file.io                                                                                                                            {"success":true,"key":"Y7PDKv","link":"https://file.io/Y7PDKv","expiry":"14 days"}
```

Comment: Shutdown? Did you read the message on their website: "Don’t Panic! transfer.sh will live on!".

Answer (score 1):

With this bash function you can obtain the link

```
snd() {
    curl --progress-bar -F "file=@$1" -s -w "\n"  https://file.io | jq -r '.link'
}
alias snd=snd
```

How To use: `snd filename.ext`

Obtain: `https://file.io/0uw5yYbkguc4`

To parse the upload response, json, need to install "jq"